# Visual Studio - Targeting Pack for Mono?

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, visual-studio-2012

Is there any where I can download a targeting pack for the Mono framework? The only thing I've found so far is this blog:

http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/target-mono-from-visual-studio/

While this approach does work (being mindful of version numbering) - it would be great if an up-to-date targeting pack was available for download - rather than having to go and make changes to the registry.

Many thanks

Mark.